# Adding lower restriction to Applet / Webstart

Tags: java, security, applet, jnlp, restrictions

I have a simple Applet application and my code creates ImageIcon objects from the same url from the Applet. When I run the application, I get a message about unrestricted access, it scares the user.

**How I configure my Applet or my JNLP to only show specific restriction messages?**

**Edited**
After all, I refactor my code and find ways to load image correctly. To load image from JAR: *http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html#images*.
To load image from Applet: `imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getImage(getCodeBase(), "image/image_name.png"));`

Comment: What is the content of the JNLP & HTML?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm try run the JNLP with:
<security><j2ee-application-client-permissions/></security>
and applet.policy:
grant {
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThreadGroup";
};

Comment: I try this because when I run the application on Netbeans without *'permission java.security.AllPermission;'*, I have this exception: *java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")*.

Comment: I found this bug: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I configure my Applet or my JNLP to only show specific restriction messages?

Beyond the more specific permissions shown for the [JNLP API services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html), Java does not offer any finer permission gradations than `all-permissions`, `j2ee-application-client-permissions` or sand-boxed (no `security` element).

---

However it seems *this* warning is seen due to a bug linked by the OP.

[Netbeans Bug 227169 - java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227169)

Comment: Andrew, do I need add permission for this?
*...
URL url = new URL(codeBase, imageName);
return new ImageIcon(url);
..*
For example, my applet run on *http://www.mvbos.com.br/blank_colony/* and I try to loag image from *http://www.mvbos.com.br/blank_colony/image/*

Comment: That should work in a sand-box, so long as `imageName` is not something ridiculous.